# Super-efficient geo-intersection operations in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, linestring, st-intersects

I am working with big spatial data. I have about 2.3 million multilinestrings (driven routes) and I seek to count the number of intersections of each individual multilinestring with a set of ~60-150 linestrings. For each of the multilinestrings, the linestring sets are not the same. The sets are non-reducable, meaning that I already employ fast filters that reduce the set of linestrings to those which actually intersect the bounding boxes of the multilinestrings.

I am working with GeoPandas in Python, and I use `gpd.options.use_pygeos = True`. My code roughly follows this logic:

```
import geopandas as gpd
def count_intersections(gdf_with_multilinestring, line_df):
    ''' takes a cluster value, reads in the relevant cluster file with the trips, 
        and counts the intersecting lines from the trips sample "all_trips" for each trip
        and associated multilinestring
    '''
   line_df = line_df[some_filters]   

   return len(
        gpd.sjoin(gdf_with_multilinestring, line_df, how="inner", op="intersects")
    )
```

It's all a bit more complicated than that, but what I basically do is use GeoPandas to spatially join each `gdf_with_multilinestring` (one row) with `line_df` (up to 150 rows and more), retain only matching entries and take the number of intersections. Right now, one intersects operation takes about 3.5 seconds.

Assuming that all other steps are sufficiently efficient, is there any way to reduce the time of the spatial join of these two GeoDataFrames? It does not need to be in GeoPandas, any Python or even R implementation would help.

Comment: Probably not, since I have 2.3 million multilinestrings and approximately 30 million linestrings. The big line dataframe of 30 million is filtered in every function call.

Comment: Intersection performance is based on the product of the number of vertices in the two features. When all features overlap all other features, spatial indexing is of no benefit. You have to change the problem so that it can scale.

Comment: `geopandas.sjoin` is vecotrized so using a single row gdf is super inefficent. try to do the join first and then filter after.

Comment: @martinfleis the reason that `gdf_with_multilinestring` is one row is that the filters on `line_df` depend on attributes (mostly time) of the paricular row. So let's assume I take all 2.3M MultiLineString rows that I have for possible `gdf_with_multilinestring`s togeher in one big GeoDataFrame and join them onto the 34M big unfiltered `line_df`, do you think this is more efficient than 2.3M single joins with a filtered ~60 observation `line_df`? Maybe I should try that

Comment: That is hard to tell. It heavily depends on the spatial structure of your data and the related efficiency of the spatial index.

Comment: In my case, it was a matter of points and polygons, but I was in a similar situation. In my case, I was able to shorten the processing time very much by using Numpy. Similarly, I think using Numpy to pick out the 30million lines that need to intersect and then work on them, which will give you some time. Of course, this is a matter that depends to the extent of the structure of the data.